# What is the projective dual of a planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, plane-geometry

Everybody learns the usual definition of the dual of a planar graph when edges are preserved and faces are mapped to vertices. Everybody learns the projective duality. What if we apply it to a geometric graph, do we get a useful notion?

The vertices would be mapped to lines and edges to "hourglasses" (aka double wedges) in a certain way. Planarity ensures that every line is contained in at most one hourglass (except the lines corresponding to the vertices). Has this been ever studied/used to solve a problem?